# Nodes not connecting during cypher command

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a location, create a meeting, find 2 people by their index, then connect them all together. First I got yelled at for not having WITH between Merge and Match but when the query runs, I get 2 people connected to a meetup, but the location is an empty node and the location node is floating in space. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
MERGE (location:Location{location_name:"Starbucks", address:"300 S Main St", city: "Ann Arbor", state: "MI", zip_code:"48104", phone_number:"", web_address:""}) WITH location

MERGE(m:Meetup{meet_date:"2015-09-17", meet_time:"14:00:00",status:"Pending",did_happen:""})
WITH m

MATCH(p1:Person{username:"wkolcz"})

MATCH(p2:Person{username:"stubbe"})

MERGE (p1)-[:REQUESTED]->(m)<-[:WAS_REQUESTED]-(p2)

MERGE (m)-[:MEETUP_AT]->(location)-[:HOSTED_MEETUP]->(m)
```

Comment: Do you want to ensure that the `Location` and `Meetup` exist, even if either `Person` is not found? Or, do you only want to make a change to the DB if both persons are found?

Comment: people should always be found, it's the user and a person he finds on the site first. The meetup will always be created and the location can be found or made. Should I change the meeting to CREATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to change the two `MATCH` statements on `Person` nodes to use `MERGE` (unless these nodes already exist in your graph).

Secondly, in the `WITH` clause you must add `location`. You must include any variables in the `WITH` statement that you want to bring through to the next part of the query. More info on `WITH` [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html)

Here's the full query:

```
MERGE (location:Location{location_name:"Starbucks", address:"300 S Main St", city: "Ann Arbor", state: "MI", zip_code:"48104", phone_number:"", web_address:""}) WITH location
MERGE (m:Meetup{meet_date:"2015-09-17", meet_time:"14:00:00",status:"Pending",did_happen:""})
WITH m, location
MERGE (p1:Person{username:"wkolcz"})
MERGE (p2:Person{username:"stubbe"})
MERGE (p1)-[:REQUESTED]->(m)<-[:WAS_REQUESTED]-(p2)
MERGE (m)-[:MEETUP_AT]->(location)-[:HOSTED_MEETUP]->(m)
```

Comment: Do I need the first WITH? Or just a with between the MATCH and MERGE?

Comment: The first WITH (after merging on location) is not needed because at that point `location` is the only bound variable in scope.